# efivars data missing from procfs and sysfs

Tags: grub2, uefi

I'm trying to install ubuntu on a Tab-X 10.1 Intel WinPad.

The UEFI loader only allows booting from 32 bit efi images.
Ubuntu only supports UEFI in 64 bit versions.

I'm trying to get the 64 bit version of Ubuntu to generate a 32 bit EFI image -
I installed `grub-efi-ia32` replacing `grub-efi-amd64`.

When reinstalling grub-efi, it complained that:

```
Fatal: Couldn't open either sysfs or procfs directories for accessing EFI variables.
```

I checked, and the efivars module is loaded. `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` exists and is empty. `/sys/firmware/efi/vars` does not exist.

I couldn't mount efivarfs because it doesn't seem to be installed.

I'm a bit stuck - any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times when you get `Fatal: Couldn't open either sysfs or procfs directories for accessing EFI variables.` is due that you didn't boot using UEFI. This variables only show when the running system was boot with UEFI, using the CSM they are not enabled... so this is a chicken/egg problem, for you to setup UEFI, you need to boot using UEFI! :)

So try to setup as much as you can then grab the rEFInd usb or CD image and use it to boot the system the first time. After this to finish the setup without any problem.

Comment: (The cycle-breaker is `EFI/boot/bootx64.efi`, or in this case `EFI/boot/bootia32.efi`, which is how boot images like the ones you mention use.  It might be possible to copy grub.efi to that path in the ESP temporarily, to achieve the same effect).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the system to boot by stealing a 32-bit efi image from a live CD that supported  32-bit EFI (Clonezilla), and modifying the grub.cfg to point to the right HDD.

For unknown reasons, I had to manually go into the EFI shell, and start the grubia32.efi from there.

Once booted, I installed `grub-efi-ia32` and `boot-repair`.

Running boot-repair did some magic and got it working.

Comment: Probably because none of the BOOTXXXX variables pointed to grubia32.efi and there was no default bootloader configured